# PSpell in Quercus?

Tags: php, quercus

We're running Quercus on Glassfish to serve the odd PHP file.

I'm wondering if its possible to get PSpell/ASpell(?) spellchecker(s) working in Quercus?

It seems for normal PHP you need to compile it w/ PSpell so I'm not too sure how to go about this in Quercus ...

Any pointers greatly appreciated :P

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend switching to [php-java-bridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/), if possible. Quercus locks you into their version of php and you have to be dependent on them to port the extensions to their version. The php-java-bridge gives you access to the complete access to the 'official' php functionality and extensions.

I evaluated Quercus for use in a project, but soon realised that the required extensions were not available and switched to php-java-bridge.

Answer (score 0):

http://upgradephp.berlios.de/pspell.txt

Incomplete. Don't know much about Quercus. But you might need to change the backtick operator to exec(). Oh, and of course it requires a working aspell binary. It's just a wrapper to the cmdline utility.

Contribute back :P